# Posting with Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have nested my resources (see below) and when I try to create a new entity, I get the following error. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error and how to solve it?

> undefined method `applications' for nil:NilClass

```
resources careers do
    resources applications
end
```

Within the 'Applications' controller I have:

```
before_filter [[:authenticate, :except => :new], :load_career]

def create
      # The following line is where the error originates
    @application = @career.applications.new(params[:application])

    respond_to do |format|
        ...
    end
end

private
def load_career
    @career = Career.find(params[:career_id])
end
```

The `Career` and `Application` models have `has_many :applications` and `belongs_to :career` respectively.

And the '*_create_applications' migration has a `career_id` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen before_filters defined that way. I just tried it in Rails 3 and it doesn't seem to do anything. I would give each callback it's own before_filter call:

```
before_filter :authenticate, :except => :new
before_filter :load_career
```